# Instantiating gameObject relative to its parent Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, game-engine

I want to instantiate an object relative to its parent. To be more precise I need to instantiate a cube on the surface of the plane which will be moved and rotated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sample code would be good to fix. Or just try instantiating the cube as the child of the plane with the local offset, This will do.

Comment: I tried this: `public GameObject cube;

    Quaternion rotoffset;
    Vector3 posoffset;
 
 void Start () {
        rotoffset = transform.rotation;
        posoffset = transform.position;
        Instantiate(cube, posoffset,rotoffset);
    }` but I have no idea how to move the object correctly from this position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's simple enough...

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SpawnChild(GameObject prefab, Vector3 relativePosition, Quaternion relativeRotation = Quaternion.identity)
    {
        GameObject childObj = Instantiate(prefab);
        childObj.transform.parent = transform;
        childObj.transform.localPosition = relativePosition;
        childObj.transform.localRotation = relativeRotation;
        childObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```